# What are the rules for capitalizing the second part of a hyphenated word in a title?

Tags: hyphens, capitalization

I would assume that it both parts of the hyphenated word would be capitalized in a standard example (e.g. From the Mixed-Up Files of Mrs. Basil E. Frankweiler). However, I noticed in my piano book, it has a section called The Controversy of B-flat. Notice the uncapitalized flat. Are there special rules for music, or is it the book that's wrong? Furthermore, how do I capitalize hyphenated words with prefixes (e.g. anti-intellectual)? If there's a complete list of capitalization rules for hyphenated words, I'd like to hear it.

Comment: Link (that I think you might already have read) https://www.businesswritingblog.com/business_writing/2010/08/capitalizing-hyphenated-words-in-titles.html

Comment: Thank you. This still doesn't answer my question about the music, though. I know someone told me more complete rules somewhere. Thanks, though.

Comment: Actually it is detailed about music, quoting the Chicago guide: "[For titles,] capitalize any subsequent elements unless they are articles, prepositions, coordinating conjunctions (and, but, for, or, nor), or such modifiers as flat or sharp following musical key symbols.

Comment: I'm so sorry that I didn't notice that!

Answer (score 3):

There's no hard and fast 'rule', but professional organisations that produce literature tend to have 'style-guides' (or refer to a respected one) so as to have consistency of output among writers. Several style-guides, including *The Chicago Manual of Style*, the *Publication Manual of the American Psychological Association*, and the *MLA Handbook from the Modern Language Association*, say that you should capitalise all the main words in hyphenated words in titles and headings.

With regard to your music example - I would say that 'B-flat' is *not* a compound noun. Compound nouns generally bring words together to create something that incorporates the meanings of all the words. A 'B-flat' in music is a completely unique note, the only relation to 'B' being its position on the scale, my point being that the hyphen is not there to join two 'words' together. While many symbols used in English writing are substitutes for words, the reverse is true with music - music is written as symbols on a stave, and we have words to represent them.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification on music.

Answer (score -3):

Well, in English we capitalize all the words with the exception of prepositions and determiners. Exceptions are determiners and prepositions at the beginning of the title. The reason why flat is small is because B-flat is one word. "B" on its own is not a word, it's just letter. Anti-intellectual would be "Anti-Intellectual", because it consists of two words.

Comment: Thank you, but in the article linked above, the Chicago Manual of Style says this:                                  "If the first element is merely a prefix or combining form that could not stand by itself as a word (anti, pre, etc.), do not capitalize the second element unless it is a proper noun or proper adjective."                                                 This manual seems to be the most popular one on this subject, but everyone has different opinions. And I know there's a more complete source somewhere.

Comment: Also, "anti" isn't a word, it's a prefix, and it sometimes doesn't even need a hyphen. e.g. "My toothpaste has antisensitivity, so it doesn't irritate my cankor sore."                                          P.S. At this point I'm just curious. I originally asked this question just to make sure I had The Blueish-Brown Prophecy spelled right. (my new novel)